# IndexError:index 58 is out of bounds for size 58

Tags: python, matplotlib, indexing, roc, rfe

I'm using RFECV to train some data to get the best accuracy with the appropriate number of features.But I kept getting the same error as mentioned in the title.Below is the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve,auc

data=sio.loadmat('B.mat')#B is trainData,shape (68L,160L)
X=data['B']

label=sio.loadmat('label.mat')#label is the target values,shape(68L,)
y=label['label'].reshape(68)
# Create the RFE object and compute a cross-validated score.
cv=StratifiedKFold(y,7)
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
svc = SVC(kernel="linear",probability=True,random_state=random_state)
# The "accuracy" scoring is proportional to the number of correct
# classifications
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(y, 7),
              scoring='accuracy')


#rfecv.fit(trainData,trainLabel)

for i, (train, test) in enumerate(cv):
    probas_ = rfecv.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
    # Compute ROC curve and area the curve
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y[test], probas_[:, 1])
    #mean_tpr += interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr)
    #mean_tpr[0] = 0.0
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, lw=1, label='ROC fold %d (area = %0.2f)' % (i, roc_auc))


print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)

# Plot number of features VS. cross-validation scores
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Cross validation score (nb of correct classifications)")
plt.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.grid_scores_) + 1), rfecv.grid_scores_)
plt.show()
```

The error happens in `probas_ = rfecv.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])`, and I really don't know what the mistake is.
the entire traceback is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/zhouzhen/python/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.py", line 37, in <module>
    probas_ = rfecv.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\rfe.py", line 416, in fit
    X_train, y_train = _safe_split(self.estimator, X, y, train)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1591, in _safe_split
    X_subset = safe_indexing(X, indices)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 163, in safe_indexing
    return X.take(indices, axis=0)
IndexError: index 58 is out of bounds for size 58

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I debugged this, and found it's confusing.

Comment: Python has 0 based indices. So for a size of 58, you can only access indices [0...57].

Comment: If I understand it right you have 68 data points and probably 58 of them are going to be in training set with the rest in validation during the cross-validation loop. I'm guessing there is a format error in your data set.

Comment: I know this, and I debugged the program, just can' locate the mistake.

Comment: if you know that the problem is in data set format then putting the code here does not help much. If checking the file itself is hard maybe just try doing a manual binary search by first using one half of the matrix (data[:34, : ]) and then the second half (data[34: , :]), and so on. Hopefully there is only one mistake and you'll be able to find the row number of the mistaken data.

Comment: You didn't provide a reproducible code that we can run. Please provide your B.mat and label.mat files if you want to get any help

Comment: yes, I wanted to, but I don't know where to upload the  B.mat and label.mat files.